# What are the main reasons of Arjuna for not wanting to fight the Mahabharata war initially?

Tags: mahabharata, arjuna, war

What are the main reasons of Arjuna for not wanting to fight the Mahabharata war initially?

How could he change his attitudes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What are the main reasons of Arjuna for not wanting to fight the Mahabharata war initially?**

His attachment with kinsmen and incomplete knowledge of Dharama:

गाण्डीवं स्रंसते हस्तात्त्वक्चैव परिदह्यते।

न च शक्नोम्यवस्थातुं भ्रमतीव च मे मनः।।1.30।।

I also do not foresee any good by killing my own kinsmen in the battle. O Krsna! I wish niether victory, nor kingdom, nor the pleasures [thereof].

येषामर्थे काङ्क्षितं नो राज्यं भोगाः सुखानि च।

त इमेऽवस्थिता युद्धे प्राणांस्त्यक्त्वा धनानि च।।1.33।।

[These are our] teachers, fathers, sons and also paternal grandfathers, maternal uncles, fathers-in-law, son's sons, wives' brothers, and (other) relatives.

तस्मान्नार्हा वयं हन्तुं धार्तराष्ट्रान्स्वबान्धवान्।

स्वजनं हि कथं हत्वा सुखिनः स्याम माधव।।1.37।।

How could we be happy indeed, O Madhava, after slaying our own kinsmen ?

अहो बत महत्पापं कर्तुं व्यवसिता वयम्।

यद्राज्यसुखलोभेन हन्तुं स्वजनमुद्यताः।।1.45।।

Alas! What a great sinful act have we resolved to undertake ! For, out of greed for the joy of kingdom, we are striving to slay our own kinsfolk !

यदि मामप्रतीकारमशस्त्रं शस्त्रपाणयः।

धार्तराष्ट्रा रणे हन्युस्तन्मे क्षेमतरं भवेत्।।1.46।।

It would be more beneficial for me if Dhrtarastra's men with weapons in their hands, should slay me, unresisting and unarmed.

**How could he change his attitudes?**

Arjuna was not ready to change his attitude easily which resulted in 18 chapters of Srimad BhagavadGita. You may need to read all 18 chapters to find the answer of this question.

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of other question. Please check for duplicates before answering.

Comment: @NogShine Yes, I checked that comment later as i was writing answer that time..only few seconds difference is there in my answer and comment.. I have also voted now for a duplicate.. will search first in this site from next time... bdw I believe all related question appears when someone asks a question..is there any problem with Suggestion (while asking a question) in this site now a days?..

Comment: I don't think that there is any problem with the suggestions. If similar words ate not sued, sometimes the search may fail to show exact duplicates. The problem rises there. Some people (not this particular case) tend to ask even if they find the question. We can't  help them but vote to close them before answering. We can prevent answers to dupes by being quick in moderation.

Comment: @NogShine okay..sounds good...

Comment: Your answer is super comparing to answer of existing as marked as duplicate of that